# How to limit holdout to one or more objects?

Tags: masking

Selecting in the "materials properties" of a certain object (the "masking object") the shader "holdout" will make **any** (part of an) object that is in the scene behind the masking object disappear.

How can I **limit** this effect to **one or more objects** only, so that all other objects in the scene are unaffected by the masking effect of the masking object?

Answer (score 5):

Using view layers:

[image]

Setup your scene with 3 collections:

- One for the objects that won't be masked
- One for the objects to mask
- One for the holdout object

Then create a layer for the "no hold out":

[image]

- No hold out collection is rendered
- Holdout collection is indirect only
- Holdout object is disabled

And a layer for the hold out:

[image]

- No holdout part is indirect only
- Holdout part is rendered.

In the compositor:

[image]

The hold out layer is alpha over for either alpha parts of the holdout layer or for the parts where holdout depth is greater than the no holdout one.

All is rendered with a transparent film.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use *Boolean* with *Difference* as a workaround. The solution by Lemon is rather complex, not intuitive and in some cases won't help.

In my case where I have multiple holdout planes and each of them has its own object to hide, but can't hide objects of other holdout planes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.